# How to pass argument to the button's onClick function?(Android)

Tags: android, onclick, arguments, parameter-passing

> Description:

I have onClick Function called `sum(View v)`. How can I pass the arguments to the mentioned function?  I tried  `sum(View v,int a,int b)` but as soon as i do this, Compiler throws an error as `"Corresponding method handler 'public void sum(android.view.View)' not found"`. First, tell me, is it possible to pass an argument to the on click Function in the same way as I did or there is some other way to do the same.

> desired java code:

```
     public void sum(view v,int a,int b){
        int c;
        c =a+b;
}
```

find some related questions on the forum but did not get satisfied with the answers. Ask me to provide more if needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have hardcoded in xml the `onClick` attribute of the button (let's say it's a button) like:

```
android:onClick="sum"
```

then the sum method must have this signature:

```
public void sum(View v)
```

no other parameters are allowed for `sum()` only `View v` (even though the app will compile but when you click the button then the app will crash).  
If you want you to use these 2 integer variables inside `sum()` then you have to declare them at the class level.  
**Edit** So declare 2 variables in your activity class

```
int a = 0;
int b = 0;
```

you can set their values anywhere in this class and when you click the button, inside `sum()` you can access them.

Comment: And what if i need to change the value of variable for the every call of function at different places. Declaring variable at class level(or globally ) make variable as constant for each call.

Comment: *Declaring variable at class level(or globally ) make variable as constant for each call* no it does not! It's a variable not **final**.

Comment: suppose i declared the variable a =0 & b= 0. Now I want to call the sum(View v) function at three different places with different values of a & b. How is it possible to do this?

Comment: You don't call `sum()`, it is triggered when you click the button, isn't this the reason  for your question? When you click the button, inside `sum()` you can put code to use a and b. Their values could have been changed anywhere in the class.

Comment: now this question started bothering me. Your last answer totally confused me. can you please write brief code for what you said above?

Comment: In your question you write *I have onClick Function called sum(View v)*, this means that you want this function to be executed every time you click the button so I suppose in xml you have set this attribute for the button: `android:onClick="sum"`. Isn't this the case? So `sum()` will be executed **when you click the button**. Now inside the body of `sum()` you can do whatever you want with a and b, like showing a toast: `Toast.makeText(this, "the value of a is=" + a, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

Comment: Whatever you write above is right. Now If I call that sum() function on three different places the value of 'a' will be same in the toast for every call because once you declare the value of 'a', it will remain same in all three places. Even if you change 'a', it will change for all three places. And we can't change the value of 'a' at the time of calling. Bacause we didnot passed the arguments. Sorry for bothering u.

Comment: **You don't call sum()** it's called by the system when you click the button. If you want to change the value of `a` you **can** do it anywhere in your class (including inside `sum()`) so **when** you click the button you can manage the new value of `a` inside `sum()`.

Comment: Ohh sorry.... How can i make such big mistake. We can't call the OnClick function because it will get call everytime i press the button. So there is nothing about arguments.

Comment: @AniketJadhav exactly this is the case

Answer (score 0):

> How can I pass the arguments to the mentioned function?

Generally, you don't. Using data binding lambda expressions in your layout, you could, but that is a relatively advanced topic.

Instead, you could:

- Rename your `sum(View v)` method to be `onSumClicked(View v)` and adjust wherever you are using that method to match
- Have `onSumClicked(View v)` call your `sum(view v,int a,int b)` with your desired values

Comment: bit confused. can you please write the code for what you said above? i am a beginner in android.